# install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good but no such element or plugin 'v4l2src'

Tags: linux, embedded, gstreamer, debian-jessie

i have an embedded device (friendlyarm smart4418) with debian jessie linux. i install gstreamer 1.0 and install all gstreamer pluggins.
when run

```
gst-inspect-1.0 -b
```

output is

```
libgstvideo4linux2.so
```

but when run

```
gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2src
```

output is

```
No such element or plugin 'v4l2src'
```

and output of `dpkg -L gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` is

```
> /.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgst1394.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaasink.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstalaw.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstalphacolor.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstalpha.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstapetag.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudiofx.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudioparsers.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstauparse.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstavi.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcacasink.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcairo.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcutter.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstdebug.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstdeinterlace.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstdtmf.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstdv.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgsteffectv.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstequalizer.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstflac.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstflv.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstflxdec.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstgdkpixbuf.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstgoom.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstgoom2k1.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgsticydemux.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstimagefreeze.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstinterleave.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstid3demux.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstjack.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstjpeg.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlevel.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmatroska.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmonoscope.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmulaw.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmultifile.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmultipart.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnavigationtest.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstpng.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstossaudio.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstoss4audio.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstisomp4.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstreplaygain.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtp.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtpmanager.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtsp.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstshapewipe.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstshout2.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsmpte.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsouphttpsrc.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstspectrum.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstspeex.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgsttaglib.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstudp.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideobox.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideocrop.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideofilter.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideomixer.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvpx.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstwavenc.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstwavpack.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstwavparse.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstximagesrc.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgsty4menc.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/locale
/usr/share/locale/ja
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_HK
/usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/sr
/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/sq
/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/sl
/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/ro
/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/or
/usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/nl
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/nb
/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/mt
/usr/share/locale/mt/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/mt/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/lv
/usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/id
/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/hu
/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/gl
/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/fi
/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/eu
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/es
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/eo
/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/en_GB
/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/de
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/da
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/af
/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/hr
/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/el
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/vi
/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/uk
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/tr
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/sk
/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/pl
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/lt
/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/it
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/cs
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/ca
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/bg
/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/locale/az
/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/gst-plugins-good-1.0.mo
/usr/share/gstreamer-1.0
/usr/share/gstreamer-1.0/presets
/usr/share/gstreamer-1.0/presets/GstIirEqualizer10Bands.prs
/usr/share/gstreamer-1.0/presets/GstIirEqualizer3Bands.prs
/usr/share/gstreamer-1.0/presets/GstVP8Enc.prs
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/copyright
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/AUTHORS
```

Comment: Do you have anaconda or miniconda installed? Could you check running `which gst-inspect-1.0` on terminal?

Comment: can you post the output of command " locate libgstvideo4linux2.so", seems like you have 2 instances.

Comment: hi _ Alper Kucukkomurler_  output of  `which gst-inspect-1.0`  is `/usr/bin/gst-inspect-1.0`

Comment: hi _Prabhakar_ output of  `locate libgstvideo4linux2.so` is `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so`

Comment: i have another problem that maybe related,  **gst-plugin-scanner** hangs and I kill it.

Comment: running gst-inspect-1.0 directly on the binary might tell you why it failed to load